# $\bar{L}$ is image path of $L$ by the function $z \mapsto\bar{z}$.Prove that $z \mapsto\overline{f(\bar{z})}$ is continuous on $L$

Tags: complex-analysis

I stumbled across this question from my assignment on complex analysis -

Let $L$ be a path and $\bar{L}$ the path which is the image of $L$ by the function $z \rightarrow \bar{z}$. Let $f$ be a continuous function on $L.$ Prove that the function $z \mapsto\overline{f(\bar{z})}$ is continuous on $L.$

Comment: It is the composition of three continuous functions ($z\mapsto\bar z,f,$ and $w\mapsto\bar w$). Beware, it is not on $L$ but on $\bar L.$

Comment: Can you explain in a little detail please

Comment: ??? What is it you don't understand? the fact that it is the composition of these 3 functions? the fact that they are continuous? the consequence that the composite is continuous? the fact that this composite is defined on $\bar L$ and not on $L?$

Comment: it is given that f is continuous on L ,how do we say that f is also continuous on $\bar L$?

Comment: $f$ is not even defined on $\bar L.$ Compare with my first comment.